# Excel cell name increments

Tags: microsoft-excel

Please, how do I make cells names increment by a certain number when embedded in a formula when I auto fill? For instance, how do I make the cell name E2 change to E4 in the next cell and E6 in the following cell when I auto fill in a formula like this =IF(E2="","",IF(E2=1,"Wow","Need Help"))

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in F2 and fill down:

```
=IF(INDIRECT("E"&2*(ROW()-1))="","Blank",IF(INDIRECT("E"&2*(ROW()-1))=1,"Wow","It Works"))
```

[image]